# HTML5 Canvas Particle Effect with icons

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, jquery-animate

I need help for this particle effect with icons floating on background and on mousescroll all the icons should evaluate to next screen with animation as attached below.

[image: First Screen]

[image: Second Screen]

can anybody will help me to solve this task.

Comment: please provide us with some code of what you have been trying to do. this will help us help you!

Comment: Actually i dont have knowledge of canvas animation, so m searching for the same if any. please help me out with the scratch code if you can.

Answer (score 1):

This quick demo animates 1+ images from their individual `[startX, startY]` to their individual `[endX, endY]` over a specified number of animation frames.

You can trigger it by listening for `mousewheel` events on IE and `DOMMouseScroll` events on other browsers.

**Quick example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var images=[];

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/shipSmall.jpg";
function start(){
    images.push(defineImageAnimation(img,20,20,200,100,60*2));
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function animate(time){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    var stillAnimating=false;
    for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
        var img=images[i];
        if(img.durationCountdown>0){
            img.x+=img.dx;
            img.y+=img.dy;
            img.durationCountdown--;
            stillAnimating=true;
        }else{
            img.x=img.endX;
            img.y=img.endY;
        }
        ctx.drawImage(img.image,img.x,img.y);
    }
    if(stillAnimating){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
}

// duration is expressed as how many requestAnimationFrame loops it
//     should take the animation to complete. Loops occur about every
//     1/60th of a second
function defineImageAnimation(img,startX,startY,endX,endY,duration){
    return({
        image:img,
        x:startX, y:startY,
        endX:endX, endY:endY,
        dx:(endX-startX)/duration,
        dy:(endY-startY)/duration,
        durationCountdown:duration
    });
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But it's not satisfied.
I need few particles moving in the background and when scroll all the particles should get together in a shape as i had attached jpeg example above.
Note : Particles should be any icons.
Do let me know if you can help me out.

Comment: I won't do your project for you! :-o  The answer shows you how to animate your images which is the complex part of your project.

Comment: i am not asking the whole project can you help me how to make  background images to evaluate in a shape on scroll as i have some example for you.
[Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-3D-Interative-Parallax-Background-Effects-with-jQuery-Simples-3D/)

Comment: You've got your starting (random) and ending design (phone). Find the starting and ending X,Y for each icon. Then use the code in the answer to animate to the ending position. Simple as that. Again, the answer does the only hard part of your project ... you need to code the rest yourself!!